Recommended math site or app for 7th/8th grade
I am looking for an app or website that teaches math at 7th or 8th grade level (for my son). The emphasis should be on fun, game-like experience, that would maintain his natural excitement and enthusiasm of the subject.
Recommendation from your personal experience would be great. Paid options are welcomed.

Perhaps try The Art of Problem Solving https://artofproblemsolving.com/community  Find the appropriate grade-level there.

First, there is not one standard "7th/8th grade level". Is your son ready for algebra, or is he working on some the the concepts that lead up to algebra?
If the latter, then I recommend Beast Academy, a full curriculum that includes great puzzles, and uses a graphic novel format, with beast students and beast teachers. Although the levels say 1 to 5, they are not grades. You can get the online version for $100 a year, which allows you to use all the levels. (BA does not do graphing.) [Disclaimer: I work part-time for Art of Problem Solving, the parent company of Beast Academy.]
If he is pretty close to ready for algebra (or at a higher level than that), he might enjoy using the pre-agebra level of Alcumus on the Art of Problem-Solving site. This is free. It is not "teaching" math as much as allowing exploration through problems.
Does he like geometry? I love the site sciencevsmagic.net's Ancient Greek Geometry page. Again, it's not "teaching"; it's allowing exploration through problems. It's a gamified way to explore geometric construction, with 40 puzzles. (There are other sites that do this. This one is my favorite.)
You wanted online, but there are some great books that encourage mathematical learning through storytelling. Two that come to mind are The Number Devil, and Marco the Great and the History of Numberville. And for a slightly higher level (comfort with square roots and basic algebra required), he might be interested in being a beta reader for my upcoming books, Althea and the Mystery of the Imaginary Numbers and Althea and the Mysteries of Triangles, Circles, and Pi.

My sons used PixelMath for middle school. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pixelmath-lite/id6475047382 I am not sure about fun but it helped them with some problems.
